# Thyme leaf show selected value from object

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot 1.3 app using Thymeleaf.  I have a screen that shows a list of users, including the institution they are associated with.  Thanks to some previous StackOverflow help, I am able to create a new user and select their institution from a drop down list.  I am now trying to do something similar for editing a user - when you edit the record, the dropdown defaults to the institution the user has already been assigned.

I have a User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institutionId", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
}
```

And an Institution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Institution")
public class Institution {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long institutionId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

And here is my HTML to edit the user record (edited):

I have attached screen shots showing a user with an assigned institution, but when I try to edit, there is no dropdown.

How do I get that drop down there, and ideally pre-selected with the user.institution?

[image]
Here you can see the edit user does not have the dropdown:

[image]

**EDIT** to show progress and clean up the question:
I have it so that the the list appears to show the institution on the user when I go to edit.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div th:if="${user.institution != null }"
        <select name="user.institution">
            <option th:each="choice : ${institutionList}"
                    th:value="${choice.institutionId}"
                    th:attr="choiceinstitutionId=${choice.institutionId}, institutioninstitutionId=*{institution.institutionId}, showselected=(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                    th:selected="(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                    th:readonly="(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                th:text="${choice.name}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${user.institution == null }">
        <div th:if="${institutionList != null and not #lists.isEmpty(institutionList)}">
            <select name="user.institution">
                    <option th:each="dropDownItem : ${institutionList}"
                            th:value="${dropDownItem.institutionId}"
                            th:text="${dropDownItem.name}" />
            </select>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${institutionList == null or #lists.isEmpty(institutionList)}">
            <div>"No Institutions were found, please create some first"</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${institutionList == null or #lists.isEmpty(institutionList)}">
        <div>"No Institutions were found, please create some first"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is very close, except that it doesn't actually set the selected dropdown value on the user object, so its set to null each time...

Comment: Can you put the method where you return the edit form?

Comment: Please post you code with GET method of form (where you loading `user` into form). Maybe you forget to add `INSTITUTION_LIST` to the `model`?

Comment: I updated the question with the GET method, as well as the latest approach to read the list and match based upon another StackOverflow posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a dumb mistake - not actually declaring the field to set.  In case anyone else runs into a similar issue, here is the correct code to display any selected value in the list, and to set it:

```
 <div th:if="${user.institution != null }">
    <select name="user.institution" th:field="*{institution}">
        <option th:each="choice : ${institutionList}"
                th:value="${choice.institutionId}"
                th:attr="choiceinstitutionId=${choice.institutionId}, institutioninstitutionId=*{institution.institutionId}, showselected=(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                th:selected="(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                th:readonly="(${choice.institutionId} == *{institution.institutionId})"
                th:text="${choice.name}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div th:if="${user.institution == null }">
    <div th:if="${institutionList != null and not #lists.isEmpty(institutionList)}">
        <select name="user.institution" th:field="*{institution}">
            <option th:each="dropDownItem : ${institutionList}"
                    th:value="${dropDownItem.institutionId}"
                    th:text="${dropDownItem.name}" />
        </select>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${institutionList == null or #lists.isEmpty(institutionList)}">
        <div>"No Institutions were found, please create some first"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```